# Why k∈Z, $1 \le k$ leads to $(k+1)/2 \le k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Inductive hypothesis is P(i) is true for all integers i($1\le i \le k$) for all integers $k \ge 1$.

Since $1 \le k$, I understand $1\le (k+1)/2$ because $2 \le k+1$

$1 \le k \Leftrightarrow 2 \le 2k \space and \space 2 \le k+1$.

So why $1 \le k$ leads to $(k+1)/2 \le k$?

[image]

Comment: $\displaystyle  \frac{k+1}{2}\le k\iff k+1\le 2k\iff 1\le k$.

Comment: For the "Case 1" $k$ is odd so write $k=2m+1$ for some $m\in\mathbf{N}_0$. This leads to $(k+1)/2=m+1\le2m+1=k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a meaning of formalism (boring), $\frac{k+1}{2}\le k$ iff $k+1\le 2k$ iff $1\le k$. BUT... before think it: given ANY two numbers $a,b$, you know that the midle point is $\frac{a+b}{2}$. The midpoint is between the two numbers $a$ and $b$. Now, if if $a=1$ and $b=k$ is a natural number (and hence, $b\ge 1$), then $\frac{a+b}{2}=\frac{1+k}{2}$, which is the middlepoint of 1 and $k$. That is $1\le\frac{k+1}{2}\le k$

Answer (score 0):

$(k+1)/2\leq k\iff 2(k+1/2)\leq 2 k\iff k+1\leq 2 k \iff k+1-k\leq 2 k-k \iff $ $1\leq k.$